# Why does Vec have trait Sync?

Tags: data-structures, rust, thread-safety

According to the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#synthetic-implementations), `Vec<T>` implements `Sync` if `T` implements `Sync`. It seems it's generated automatically by some magic, but I feel this is counter-intuitive since a naive implementation for vectors is not thread-safe.

Is `Vec<T>` in Rust really `Sync`?

Comment: Do you have a case in mind where you feel it would be an issue? It would be easier to help you understand with an example to discuss.

Comment: A naive implementation of `Vec` isn't thread-safe if you allow mutable references to it to be shared between threads. Many languages do allow that but Rust does not. In Rust, you need to wrap the value in things like `Arc`s and `Mutex`es which allow controlled mutation with safety guarantees.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implementing `Sync` means that a type guarantees that references to its values can be shared between threads, without risk of a data race in safe Rust.

Values of type `&Vec<T>` are immutable, so it's always safe to share them. The Rust borrow checker already forbids a mutable reference to exist at the same time as any other reference to the same object so this works automatically as a result of Rust's borrowing rules. Nothing can mutate a `Vec` while it's shared, so a data race is impossible. Of course, if `unsafe` code comes into the picture then the guarantees are gone.

Most types are `Sync` in fact. The ones that aren't (for example `RefCell`) tend to have interior mutability, or otherwise manage references outside of the control of the compile-time borrow checker.